# Firebase realtime database rules resetting itself

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console, firebase-security

I'm wondering if anyone else is having this issue. I created a new project using Android Studio and i went to the Firebase console to edit the realtime database, but it keeps looping back to a menu to choose either locked mode or test mode after i exit the database (and publishing new rules):

"Start in locked mode
Make your database private by denying all reads and writes

Start in test mode
Get set up quickly by allowing all reads and writes to your database"

At the moment i cant save any database rules, it'll just reset to either choose locked mode or test mode. This is odd because for the pasted month it was working great until this new menu popup.

[image: Image description]

Comment: That sounds odd. Can you check your browser's developer tools to see if there are any relevant messages showing? Also: can you try to reproduce in a browser window where you have all plugins disabled?

Comment: I have the same exact problem, tried with both safari and chrome (on mac); seems independent from the browser

Comment: Never got it to work, i'll have to try something else. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pass through this by setting up the cloud firestore first. I don't know why they decided to do this.

Answer (score 9):

I just found this issue and was totally confused. I realized it resets every time I deploy because `firebase deploy` sends a `firestore.rules` file every time. I just needed to update that `firestore.rules` rather than online.

Comment: yeah was my issue, I totally forgot about that file, thanks

Comment: BLESS YOU. This has been driving me insane to the point I thought I was losing my mind- saved my sanity!

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the app on Firebase and recreated it.